# Most efficient way to do a half million math operations hourly

Tags: bash, gawk

So for personal and learning experience reasons I have started databasing weather data. I am using wgrib2 to parse the data, and importing to MySQL. Because the data is formatted in different units - wind "U" and "V" components, kelvin, etc... I have to convert it to wind speed knots, wind degrees radius, and temperature degrees C... etc.

I constructed a bash for loop that loops through all the data values, but it's rather inefficient and I'm sure there's better ways of doing this. It relies on awk, alot... and takes 15-17 minutes to parse data for about 1150 stations, each station has a table all identical structure with 160 columns in the MySQL database.

The bash arrays I have set up for TK (temp kelvin), RH (humidity), etc... have values for 1000, 975, 950, 925... etc all the way down to 100 millibars.

```
for thKey in ${!TK[@]}
do
    thRH=${RH[$thKey]}
    thTK=${TK[$thKey]}
    thTC=$(echo -| awk -v tk="$thTK" '{printf "%.1f\n", tk-273.15}')
    thWU=${WU[$thKey]}
    thWV=${WV[$thKey]}
    thTD=$(echo -| awk -v tc="$thTC" -v rh="$thRH" '{printf "%.1f\n", tc-(100-rh)/5}')
    thWD=$(echo -| awk -v wu="$thWU" -v wv="$thWV" '{printf "%.0f\n", 57.29578*(atan2(wu, wv))+180}')
    thWS=$(echo -| awk -v wu="$thWU" -v wv="$thWV" '{printf "%.1f\n", sqrt(wu*wu+wv*wv)*1.944}')
    sed -i '/\/station_id/a <'"$thKey"'T>'"$thTC"'<\/'"$thKey"'T><'"$thKey"'D>'"$thTD"'<\/'"$thKey"'D><'"$thKey"'WD>'"$thWD"'<\/'"$thKey"'WD><'"$thKey"'WS>'"$thWS"'<\/'"$thKey"'WS>' $xmlOut
done
```

As you can see by this the obvious problem is it does about 1150 * 160 calls to awk... so probably passing the master arrays to awk and only spawn awk once per loop (1/160th of what I'm doing now!) would be more efficient. But I can't seem to get the awk syntax right for this practice...

```
awk --version
```

GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)

Here's an example:

```
TK=(325,350,231,655)
echo -| awk -v tk="${TK[*]}" '{split(tk,tka,/ /)} { for (i=0; i<=NF; i++) { printf "%.1f\n", tka[i]-273.15 } } '
```

-273.1
51.9

^ this is not right. The array has 4 values, it should not return only 2.

```
echo -| awk -v tk="${TK[*]}" '{split(tk,tka,/ /)} { for (i=0; i<=length(tka); i++) { printf "%.1f\n", tka[i]-273.15 } } '
```

^ this spawns a infinite loop.

Any ideas? Maybe learn some perl and pass all this to a perl script?

Comment: Also make sure $xmlOut is in /dev/shm, tempfs or some other non-blocking IO. perl would be what I would use.

Comment: Since you're importing the data into a database, you could use the database to perform the conversions...

Comment: I'd suggest doing it in `C`, and could give a hint, if you would show, and explain, your input and desired output. Making me intuit your intent from a non-working piece of line noise will not result in anything good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, yes I'd do it all in perl.  :-)

```
TK=(325,350,231,655)
```

Oops.  watch out.  You've created a single element array with a comma-separated string as the element.

```
echo -| awk -v tk="${TK[*]}" '{split(tk,tka,/ /)} { for (i=0; i<=NF; i++) { printf "%.1f\n", tka[i]-273.15 } } '
```

`awk` arrays start at 1, not zero.

Because you assign the variable, you're not really using the STDIN data for anything other than the NF value (but you've passed in only a single element).  Instead of using NF, let's just count the result from `split` explicitly.  Maybe something like this:

```
$ TK=(325 350 231 655)
$ echo - | awk -v tk="${TK[*]}" '{fields=split(tk,tka,/ /)} { for (i=1; i<=fields; i++) { printf "%.1f\n", tka[i]-273.15 } } '
51.9
76.9
-42.1
381.9
```

As dave_thompson_085 mentions, you're sort of doing extra work by assigning the data to a variable directly instead of just sending it via STDIN.  More common would probably be something like:

```
$ echo ${TK[*]} | awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { printf "%.1f\n", $i-273.15 } } '
51.9
76.9
-42.1
381.9
```

And if you did want a start at a `perl` solution:

```
$ echo ${TK[*]} | perl -lane 'for $item (@F) {print $item-273.15}'
51.85
76.85
-42.15
381.85
```

Comment: You said everything I was going to except one: you can let awk use its default parsing: `echo $TK | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%.1f\n", $i-273.15}'` or with the comma `TK=325,250,etc; echo $TK | awk -F, ...`

Comment: Thank you! The fields=(split... is what I was missing. This has cut me down from 17 to 13 minutes. I will also consider the idea to use STDIN to shave a bit more off. And research Python.